url field in entry of type @techreport
Good morning everyone,
I need to add the URL in the bibliography for the @techreport entry type.
In my .bst file (based on apalike with some minor modifications, but not affecting those lines):
FUNCTION {techreport}
{
  output.bibitem
  list.label.output
  " \harvardyearleft " list.year * "\harvardyearright " * output.nonnull
  author "author" item.check
  title.field field.used =
    { skip$ }
    { format.title "title" output.check }
  if$
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" output.check
  address output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}

I tried to move write.url before the if statement, but it didn't work. In the .bst file, I also have the function.
FUNCTION {write.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { newline$ "URL: " url * write$ }
  if$
}

I have added url = {} to the .bib file for entries of type @techreport. I am using the natbib citation management package.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

Have you tried to move the write.url line just above the fin.entry line? I think that this line finishes up the entry.

Please tell us more about the actuall contents of a url field in an entry of type @techreport. E.g., is it url = {\url{...}}, or url = {...}, or something else? Also, have you tried placing the write.url line between the address output and new.block lines?
